# From UML Model Generating Code To List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, uml

With Visual Studio 2012, I have created an UML class diagram. From the class diagram, I generated the C# class.

Instead of presenting all code and images, I created a post at: [Code-First: From UML Class Diagram to Creating MS SQL Database](http://idedogs.blogspot.com/2012/08/code-first-from-uml-class-diagram-to.html)

When generating the code from the class diagram, I noticed, when there is a relationships, an IEnumerable type is generated.

This is OK, however I would like to use the generated code for Code First implementation. Below, I have created the Context. Currently, the Context class includes only one relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
.HasKey(o => o.ownerID)
.HasMany<Client>(o => (ICollection<Client>)o.Clients);
```

This creates a one-to-many relationship with the Owner and Client tables. Because HasMany expects an ICollection type, I casted IEnumerable to ICollection.

**My Question is:** When I generate code from the UML Class diagram, is there a way generating the relationship as an ICollection type instead of IEnumerable type. My UML Class diagram is presented on my blog. The blog's link I supplied link above.

Eventually, I would like to only create my project's Class Diagram, generate the code, create the context (which would create DB tables}, and develop utilizing Entities.

Because the Class Diagram generates relationships as IEnumerable, below, the context works when I cast to ICollection. It creates a one-to-many relationship. I would like to just create the relationships in the Class Diagram and not worry about the relationships after generating the code.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Medication> Medications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MedicalHistory> MedicalHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FeedingSchedule> FeedingSchedules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vaccine> Vaccines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Walk> Walks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WhoWalk> WhoWalks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().Property(b => b.fname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().Property(b => b.lname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().HasKey(o => o.ownerID).HasMany<Client>(o => (ICollection<Client>)o.Clients); 

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

All code can be viewed at my blog: [Code-First: From UML Class Diagram to Creating MS SQL Database](http://idedogs.blogspot.com/2012/08/code-first-from-uml-class-diagram-to.html)

I have included a sample of the UML Class Diagram Generated C# Code below. Currently, two classes are created and they have a one-to-many relationship.

```
    public class Client
    {
        public virtual int clientID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual int ownerID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

public class Owner
{
    public virtual int ownerID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The pets and owners
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IEnumerable<Client> Clients
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I would like the Class Diagram generate the Code below:

```
public class Owner
{
    public virtual int ownerID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The pets and owners
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and an another stackoverflow post helped me:

1) Update t4 files like this post: [Visual Studio Architecture Code Generation - Create List<type> rather than IEnumerable<type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592471/visual-studio-architecture-code-generation-create-listtype-rather-than-ienum)

2) I copied these files with ICollection modified and I updated the t4 reference on my UML Class Diagram on VS->Architecture->Configure Default Code Generation Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Just leave multiplicity at 1 and change your property type to literally `ICollection<Client>`